# Sentence order for a question in future tense

Tags: questions, future-tense

I just wonder about correct sentence order for a question in future tense.

1. Where will the terminals be operated?
2. Where will be the terminals operated?
3. Where the terminals will be operated?

Comment: If you insist on using the passive, #1 is the only syntactically valid version above. But I see no good reason for using passive anyway. I'd just ask ***Where will the terminals operate**?*

Comment: Thanks, my native language favors a passive voice for tools and other non-living subjects. So I still struggle with too much passive voice.

Comment: In all the years I've been coming to ELL (and ELU), I've never consciously recognised that "passive voice" might be more common in other languages than in English. But I will say that there have been *many* questions on ELL where the advice has tended to net down to *don't be so keen to use the passive voice*. I don't recall a single ELL question where the advice has been to use passive rather than active voice, where the OP was asking about that very choice in a specific context. By all means use passive, but no more than you need to.

Comment: All that said, the best way to write your sentence is #1.

Comment: @J.R.♦: All this being said, I still think the best way to write the sentence is my "active voice" version. To my mind, OP's #1 is just the best of a bad bunch (no disrespect, Leos! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - To be clear, when I said "the best," I meant the best of the three options provided by the OP. As much of an opponent of the passive voice as you are, even you, I think, would begrudgingly admit that #1 is superior to Nos. 2 and 3 (the third one doesn't even sound grammatical to me).

Comment: @J.R.♦: Not even "begrudgingly". I'm 100% behind the idea that *of OP's examples*, only #1 is even *credible*. Sometimes we do actually say things that aren't strictly "grammatical", but I doubt any native speaker would ever accept or use either of OP's examples #2 and #3. I must also admit I may have overstated my case arguing for active voice in this specific context. They're both fine - I just have a preference for active, and I think it would benefit most querents here on ELL if they took on board the idea that passive is usually overused by nns and natives trying to sound "formal".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Whether to use active or passive voice depends a lot on what is meant by "terminals" and what is meant by "operating" them. Battery terminals, airport terminals, and computer terminals are very different things. For airport terminals I probably prefer your active voice version; for computer terminals I'd prefer passive voice. (For battery terminals I'd look for a different verb than *operate*)

Comment: OP, exactly what kind of terminals are you asking about?

Comment: These were payment terminals accepting credit cards. There must be a person that operates them.

Comment: I wrote the #3 sentence originally but it stunk to me. That was probably czenglish. So I started to think what is the correct way to write such sentence and I thought that #1 is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where will the terminals be operated?" is the only good English syntax.  The others make sense, but they definitely sound foreign.